# OverLoading Methods Var cannot be resolved.

Tags: java, debugging, methods

The errors I am getting are "answer cannot be resolved". 1/4th of the way down the page. Looked online still don't see what it should be. Would it be easier to use the while loop instead? skipping the do loop completely?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RPSS{
//Main method
  public static void main(String[ ] argc) 
  {


    Scanner tnt = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String computerHand; // string variable for computer choice
    String userHand; // string variable for user choice
//    do loop begining
    do 
    {
      computerHand = computerHand();
      userHand = userHand();
      String winner = getWinner(computerHand, userHand);
      System.out.println(winner);
      System.out.print("User picks" + userHand );
      System.out.println("Computer picks " + computerHand );
      System.out.println("play again?");
      String answer = tnt.next();


    //Condition for the do-while loop HERE IS THE ERROR LOCATION 
  }while (!answer.Equals("No") && (!answer.Equals("no"))); //condition for while loop
  String answer = tnt.next();
  }

  public static String userHand(){ //method for users choice in the game

    //prints message to user giving them choices
    System.out.println("Lets play rock paper scissors");
    System.out.println("1. Rock ");
    System.out.println("2. Paper ");
    System.out.println("3. Scissors ");
    int userChoice; // user choice variable in this method
    Scanner tnt = new Scanner(System.in); // creates instance of scanner class
    userChoice = tnt.nextInt(); //reads user input
    return getChoice(userChoice); //returns user choice to master choice
  }

  public static String computerHand() //method for computer  generated choice 
  {

    int computernum =  (int)(Math.random() * (( 3) + 1));
    return getChoice(computernum);
  } 

  public static  String getChoice(int num) //method recieving both computer hand and user hand
  {
 //  if statements to place the correct choice
    String choice = "";
    if (num == 1){
      choice = "rock";
    }
    else if(num == 2){
      choice = "paper";
    }
    else if(num == 3){
      choice = "scissors";
    }
    return choice;
  }
  // Method determing the winner 
  public static String getWinner(String computerChoice, String userChoice) 
  {
    computerChoice = computerHand(); //places computerChoice variable in computerhand
    userChoice = userHand(); //does same for user choice
    String winner="";


    System.out.println( " the comp chose" + computerChoice);

    if (userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")){
      System.out.println("The computer"); } 

    else if  (userChoice.equals("Paper") && computerChoice.equals("Scissors")){
      System.out.println(" The computer wins"); 
    } 

    else if  (userChoice.equals("Scissors") && computerChoice.equals("Rock")){
      System.out.println(" The computer wins "); 
    } 
    else if (userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")){
      System.out.println(" The computer wins "); 

    } 

    if (userChoice.equals(computerChoice))
    {
      System.out.println(" There is no winner"); 
      }
   return winner;
  }

}
```

Comment: *"I would love an explanation to why I'm getting a nextString() is undefined for scanner"* - because it is. Have a look at the [JavaDocs for `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), see if you can `nextString`

Comment: The problem with `getWinner` is you only return value `if (userChoice.equals(computerChoice))`, no other conditions return any kind of value

Comment: You really want us to count lines?

Comment: Fixed the counting lines. The problem is only that I don't see why the variable cannot be resolved. I know that scope is primarily the problem here, but I don't understand where it needs to be placed.

Comment: What in blazes is `Equals`? It's spelled like a type name but used like a method name. Follow the naming conventions!

Answer (score 0):

Use `tnt.next()` which returns the next string. there is no such thing as `nextString()`.

Also, add `return winner;` at the end of `getwinner` method.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `answer` inside the braces of your `do` and then tried to use it outside the braces. Once you left the braces, the variable was out of scope.

Comment: It is the conditional. Why does that affect what is inside?

Comment: Flipping it and using a while( conditional) {   Here then place the } at the end is giving me the same issue.

Comment: That tells me, since you don't show the code, that you are still referencing a variable outside of its scope. Did you declare the variable prior to its first use? Did you declare it in a containing scope of its use? Are you still delcaring two different `answer` variables? How do you expect anyone to help unless you SHOW US THE CODE?

Comment: The conditional doesn't "affect what is inside", you have a variable `answer` declared inside that is not available outside. The scope of a variable is from its declaration to the closing brace around its declaration. You used a variable inside the braces called `answer`, then referred to a variable `answer` outside the braces, meaning that it was undefined, then defined another variable `answer` in the outer scope. Why don't you google around about variable scope in Java? You should study up on it. First. Then ask any questions that still linger. After you've studied it. First.